# handling "--More--" in perl using Expect.pm

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I have show command for a device with its Mac address, which i am executing in perl using [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod).
The output of command is more than 100 line with `--More--` at the bottom.
I am able to capture output everything before first occurance of `--More--`.
But not after that.
I tried with while loop it is not working for me.
Please help me resolve this.

Comment: are you using the Perl module [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) or the [tag:expect] program?

Comment: In perl program i am using Expect i.e. use Expect;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Suspect you're connecting to a Cisco Device. if so, issue "term len 0" upon logging onto the node. if juniper, add " | no-more" to the end of every command.

Comment: Yes i am using cisco device. i am using show command with begin/include i.e show arp | begin mac adress. i am new to this could you please give some example how to set terminal length in perl.

Comment: Ok, "term len 0" will fix your problem. Issue the command after logging onto the box. Then the whole text will be displayed for each command

Comment: Great, i've found with Cisco's that | can confuse the output (or maybe just using utility on the XR). Sometimes it's better to just do a "show arp" then use find the line you need in exp_before() .